# vb.net update asana tasks

Tags: .net, vb.net, asana

I am trying to post data back to the Asana Api using VB.NET,

I am able to retrieve data without issue but am struggling to get data back in. The below is an example of me trying to update the notes within a task.

```
Dim add As String = path + "tasks/" + t_id.Text
        request = WebRequest.Create(add)

        ' Set the authentication
        setauth()
        ' Set type to POST  
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.KeepAlive = True
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        data = "-d notes=" + t_notes.Text
        byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length

        'Write(data)
        Try
            ps = request.GetRequestStream()
            ps.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        Finally
            If Not ps Is Nothing Then ps.Close()
        End Try


        response = request.GetResponse()
```

I keep on getting a 404 error but not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

(I work at Asana)

If you want to update a task, you should be using the PUT HTTP method, not POST.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I have changed the method to PUT, and also tried changing the contenttype to application/json and sending through the request as a json string :- {"data":{"notes":blah blah}} but I'm not getting a bad request error.. do you have any tips?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (comments don't come to my inbox) - can you tell me what path you're making your request to? The value of the "add" variable in your code.